# How to display cyrillic text from a file in python?

Tags: python

I want to read some cyrilic text from a txt file in Python 3. 
This is what the text file contains.

```
абцдефгчийклмнопярстувшхыз
```

I used:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r') as myfile:
text=myfile.read()
print (text)
```

But this is the ouput in the python shell:

```
ÿþ01F45D3G89:;<=>?O@ABC2HEK7
```

Can someone explain why this is the output?

Comment: how is your file encoded ?

Comment: It was encoded in unicode. I've now changed it to utf-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python supports utf-8 for this sort of thing.

You should be able to do:

```
with open('text.txt', encoding = 'utf-8', mode = 'r') as my_file: 
...
```

Also, be sure that your text file is saved with utf-8 encoding. I tested this in my shell and without proper encoding my output was:

```
?????????????????????
```

With proper encoding:

```
file = open('text.txt', encoding='utf-8', mode='r')
text = file.read()
print(text)
абцдефгчийклмнопярстувшхы
```

Answer (score 1):

Try working on the file using codecs, you need to

import codecs

and then do

text = codecs.open('text.txt', 'r', 'utf-8')

Basically you need utf8